# Перевести страницу с историей тревог

Tags: дефект, локализация, инструменты-модератора

Думаю, страницу Post Flag History надо бы перевести.

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/6362/show-flags
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/742846/show-flags

Список фраз:

> Post Flag History
>
> for
>
> Creation Date
>   Creation User
>   Type
>   Deletion Date
>   Deletion User
>   Comment
>   Result
>
> Initial Body
>   Initial Title
>   Initial Tags
>   Comment Deleted
>   Post Migrated Away
>   Post Migrated Here
>   MigrationRejected
>   Edit Body
>   Edit Tags
>   Post Closed
>   Post Locked
>   Post Reopened
>   Post Unlocked
>
> from
>   to
>   closed as
>   via Vote
>
> Helpful
>   Declined

Comment: Многие из этих строк уже содержат переводы. Т.е. если они не используются, значит проблемы в движке. А может @PashaPash что подкрутил ;)

Comment: @alexolut ну кто ж еще, кроме меня